# Combination sum .

Tags: combinatorics

I want to evaluate the following sum :

$$S(k,k')=\sum_{i} C_{i+k}^k C_{k'-i}^{k}$$ = $$S(k,k')=\sum_{i} \binom{i+k}{k} \binom{k'-i}{k}$$

---

I tried some steps but couldnt get further than :

$S(k,k')=2*(\sum_{i}^{(k'-k)/2}C_{i+k}^k C_{k'-i}^{k})$

Comment: @JMoravitz $$\binom{n}{k}=C_n^k=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$$

Comment: What does this have to do with calculus?

Comment: its evaluation of a sum

Comment: That's just confusing... having $\binom{n}{k}$ have so many notations.  [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) mentions that $C^n_k, C^k_n, ~_nC_k, ~^nC_k, C_{n,k}$ are all used... *sigh*

Comment: I think you should want to go for a more common notation, like $\binom{n}{k}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have

$$S(k,\ell)=\sum_i\binom{i+k}k\binom{\ell-i}k\;.$$

This can be evaluated as a special case of identity $(5.26)$ in Graham, Knuth, & Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics*, which is given as

$$\sum_{0\le k\le\ell}\binom{\ell-k}m\binom{q+k}n=\binom{\ell+q+1}{m+n+1}$$

for integers $\ell,m\ge 0$ and integers $n\ge q\ge 0$. Thus

$$S(k,\ell)=\binom{k+\ell+1}{2k+1}\;.$$

Here’s a combinatorial proof.

Let $A=\{0,1,\ldots,k+\ell\}$. There are $\binom{k+\ell+1}{2k+1}$ ways to choose $2k+1$ elements of $A$. Once these have been chosen, we can split them into the $k$ smallest, the $k$ largest, and the one in the middle. Alternatively, we could pick these three parts separately. The middle element $m$ must satisfy the inequality $k\le m\le\ell$ in order to leave room for $k$ elements above and below it. Let $i=m-k$, so that $0\le i\le\ell-k$. Then there are $i+k$ members of $A$ below $m$, so there are $\binom{i+k}k$ ways to choose $k$ of them, and there are $(k+\ell)-(k+i)=\ell-i$ members of $A$ above $m$ and hence $\binom{\ell-i}k$ ways to choose $k$ of them. Thus, for a fixed $m$, and $i=m-k$, there are $\binom{i+k}k\binom{\ell-i}k$ ways to choose $2k+1$ members of $A$ so that $m$ is the middle element. Summing over $i$ then yields the result.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$S(k, l) =
\sum_{q=0}^l {q+k\choose k} {l-q\choose k}.$$

We start with an Iverson bracket valid for $q\ge 0$

$$[[0\le q \le l]]
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{z^{q}}{z^{l+1}}\frac{1}{1-z} \; dz$$

This gives for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w)^{l}}{w^{k+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{l+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\sum_{q\ge 0} {q+k\choose q} \frac{z^q}{(1+w)^q}
\; dw\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w)^{l}}{w^{k+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{l+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{(1-z/(1+w))^{k+1}}
\; dw\; dz 
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w)^{l+k+1}}{w^{k+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{l+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{(1+w-z)^{k+1}}
\; dw\; dz .$$

We evaluate  the inner integral by  taking the negative of  the sum of
the residues at $z=1$ and at $z=1+w$ and $z=\infty.$

The negative of the residue at $z=1$ is
$$\frac{1}{w^{k+1}}$$
which when substituted into the outer integral yields
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w)^{l+k+1}}{w^{2k+2}} \; dw
= {l+k+1\choose 2k+1},$$
which is the formula we are trying to establish.

Next we prove that  the residue at  infinity is
zero. This is given by
$$-\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} 
\frac{1}{z^2} z^{l+1}\frac{1}{1-1/z} 
\frac{1}{(1+w-1/z)^{k+1}}
= -\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} 
z^{l}\frac{1}{z-1} 
\frac{z^{k+1}}{(z(1+w)-1)^{k+1}}
\\ = -\frac{1}{(1+w)^{k+1}} \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} 
\frac{1}{z-1} 
\frac{z^{l+k+1}}{(z-1/(1+w))^{k+1}}.$$

This is zero by inspection, which leaves the residue at $z=1+w.$
Write
$$\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w)^{l+k+1}}{w^{k+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{l+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{(z-(1+w))^{k+1}}
\; dw\; dz .$$

We require the derivative
$$\frac{1}{k!} \left(\frac{1}{z^{l+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{(k)}
= \frac{1}{k!}
\sum_{q=0}^k {k\choose q}
(-1)^q \frac{(l+q)!}{l! \times z^{l+1+q}}
\frac{(k-q)!}{(1-z)^{1+k-q}}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^k {l+q\choose q}
(-1)^q \frac{1}{z^{l+1+q}}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{1+k-q}}.$$

Evaluate this at $z=1+w$ to get
$$\sum_{q=0}^k {l+q\choose q}
(-1)^q \frac{1}{(1+w)^{l+1+q}}
\frac{1}{(-w)^{1+k-q}}$$

and substitute into the outer integral to obtain
$$\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w)^{l+k+1}}{w^{k+1}} 
\sum_{q=0}^k {l+q\choose q}
(-1)^q \frac{1}{(1+w)^{l+1+q}}
\frac{1}{(-w)^{1+k-q}} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w)^{l+k+1}}{w^{k+1}} 
\sum_{q=0}^k {l+q\choose q}
\frac{1}{(1+w)^{l+1+q}}
\frac{1}{w^{1+k-q}} \; dw
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^k {l+q\choose q}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w)^{k-q}}{w^{2k+2-q}} \; dw.$$

The inner term here is
$$[w^{2k+1-q}] (1+w)^{k-q}.$$

But we  have $2k+1-q  \ge k+1$ while  $k-q \le  k$ so these  terms are
zero, thus concluding the proof.

**Simplified  solution.**  As  observed  elsewhere this  can  be  done
without the Iverson bracket.

Introduce
$${l-q\choose k} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{l-q-k+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+1}} \; dz.$$

This controls the range becoming zero when $q\gt l-k$ so we may extend
$q$ to infinity.

We obtain for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{l-k+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+1}}
\sum_{q\ge 0} {q+k\choose k} z^q \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{l-k+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+1}}\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{l-k+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{2k+2}}
\; dz.$$

This evaluates by inspection to
$${l-k+2k+1\choose 2k+1} = {l+k+1\choose 2k+1}.$$

Comment: that was marvellous, the way you coupled between [theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#) and combinatorics

Comment: I have never seen this complex-analytic proof before.  Nice!

Answer (score 1):

This yields to snake oil (see e.g. Wilf's ["generatingfunctionology"](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html)).
We want a special case of "Vandermonde on its head":
$$
\sum_k \binom{n - k}{r} \binom{m + k}{s}
$$
We will need the identity:
$$
\sum_k \binom{k}{n} z^k
  = \frac{z^n}{(1 - z)^{n + 1}}
$$
and negative binomial coefficients:
$$
\binom{-n}{k} 
  = (-1)^k \binom{n + k - 1}{n - 1}
$$
Choose $n$ as free variable, so our sum is $s_n$, and consider the generating function:
$\begin{align}
S(z) &= \sum_{n \ge 0} s_n z^n \\
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} z^n \sum_k \binom{n - k}{r} \binom{m + k}{s} \\
     &= \sum_k \binom{m + k}{s} \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n - k}{r} z^n \\
     &= \sum_k \binom{m + k}{s} z^k \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n - k}{r} z^{n - k} \\
     &= \sum_k \binom{m + k}{s} z^k \sum_j \binom{j}{r} z^j \\
     &= \sum_k \binom{m + k}{s} \frac{z^k \cdot z^r}{(1 - z)^{r + 1}} \\
     &= \frac{z^{r - m}}{(1 - z)^{r + 1}} \sum_k \binom{m + k}{s} z^{m + k} \\
     &= \frac{z^{r - m}}{(1 - z)^{r + 1}} \cdot \frac{z^s}{(1 - z)^{s + 1}} \\
     &= \frac{z^{r + s - m}}{(1 - z)^{r + s + 2}}
\end{align}$

Now we want:

$\begin{align}
s_n
  &= [z^n] S(n) \\
  &= [z^n] \frac{z^{r + s - m}}{(1 - z)^{r + s + 2}} \\
  &= [z^{m + n - r - s}] \frac{1}{(1 - z)^{r + s + 2}} \\
  &= (-1)^{m + n - r - s} \binom{-r - s - 2}{n + m - r - s} \\
  &= \binom{r + s + 2 + m + n - r - s - 1}{r + s + 2 - 1} \\
  &= \binom{m + n + 1}{r + s + 1}
\end{align}$